# Stable ID for sap.tnt.NavigationListItem (id vs. key)

Tags: sapui5

According to the [Use Stable IDs](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/79e910e6a0d949c7acb051b33170bebc) article, it is recommended to use stable IDs for the UI5 elements. At the same time, I've reviewed multiple samples of `sap.tnt.NavigationListItem` implementation and I've paid attention that in case of `sap.tnt.NavigationListItem` no `id` is used but `key`, e.g.:

```xml
<tnt:NavigationListItem text="{name}" icon="{icon}" key="{controller}" select="onItemSelect" />
```

I've also tried to assign `id` to `tnt:NavigationListItem` and then access it from the `oEvent`-object via the standard `oEvent.getProperty("%MY_ID%")` approach but no success.

My questions:

1. When should I use `id` and when `key` for UI5-items in XML-templates?
2. Is it particular `sap.tnt.NavigationListItem` case that `key` is preferred over `id` or I just  missed something important?

Comment: Keys are there for data. ID's are there for the UI. We use ID's only if we need to attache something e.g. assistant text etc.  The concept of stable IDs also dosen't work for anything in an aggregation.

Comment: I wanted to use ID to specify an UI logic, e.g. if clicked on «item_A», then do «A».

Comment: In that case use the key. The ID would be some enumerated (meaning some integer appended) thing not related to the actual data of clicked item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, I made a small example.

- If your items are hard-coded definitely go for the `key` in the
  XML definition.
- If your items come over a model. You can do the same
  as everywhere else. Use the data to trigger the right action.

Use the `ID` if you need to identify the UI element e.g. buttons in a test or if you add [User Assistance Help](https://blogs.sap.com/2020/01/07/sap-fiori-for-sap-s-4hana-how-to-setup-the-user-assistant-in-your-s-4hana-fiori-launchpad/).

```js
sap.ui.controller("view1.initial", {

onInit: function(oEvent) {
    this.getView().setModel(
      new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel({
       items: [{
            title : "1",
          subItems: [
            { keyInData: "1", title : "1-a" },
            { keyInData: "2", title : "1-b" },
            { keyInData: "3", title : "1-c" },
            { keyInData: "4", title : "1-d" }
          ]
       }],
    }));
},

onItemSelect: function(oEvent) {
     const item = oEvent.getParameter("item")
     console.log("key over key binding: " + item.getKey() )
     console.log("key over databinding: " + item.getBindingContext().getObject().keyInData )
}

});

sap.ui.xmlview("main", { viewContent: jQuery("#view1").html() } ).placeAt("uiArea");
```

```html
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
src="https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"
data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex"
data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge"
data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"></script>

<div id="uiArea"></div>

<script id="view1" type="ui5/xmlview">
  <mvc:View controllerName="view1.initial" xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns:tnt="sap.tnt">
      <tnt:NavigationList
      id="navigationList"
      width="320px"
      selectedKey="subItem3" items="{/items}">
      <tnt:NavigationListItem text="{title}"  items="{ path:'subItems', templateShareable:false}" icon="sap-icon://employee" >
        <tnt:NavigationListItem text="{title} - {keyInData}" key="{keyInData}" select="onItemSelect" />
      </tnt:NavigationListItem>
    </tnt:NavigationList>
  </mvc:View>
</script>
```